# How do I capture incoming and outgoing xml when I call a web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I am calling a third part web service from a windows application. I just tried to capture the xml response and request generated by that web service while I called it, but failed. While searching Google I found lots of articles, followed their instructions and code, but nothing works.

As examples of what I found, I followed [these instructions](http://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/kb/How_do_I_capture_the_SOAP_API_Request_and_Response%3F) and [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179346.aspx).

Can anyone tell me any easy way to capture incoming and outgoing xml when I call and work with web service returning and accepting XML?

Comment: Is it just for debugging purposes?

Comment: You can probably use fiddler for this if you simply want to view the request/response : http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13261093/932418

Comment: when i am calling 3rd part web service from our win apps then how can i view request/response xml by fiddler or wireshark.

Comment: what was the wrong in my approach which i followed. can't we programmatically capture incomming/outgoing xml from web service client end.looking for suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) you are able to capture http traffic on the client.

I'm normally using Fiddler, it registeres as a proxy on the client so if the application is using the proxy settings defined in the *Internet Options* all traffic automatically shows up after starting Fiddler.

Comment: when i am calling 3rd part web service from our win apps then how can i view request/response xml by fiddler or wireshark.

Comment: what was the wrong in my approach which i followed. can't we programmatically capture incomming/outgoing xml from web service client end.looking for suggestion.

Comment: Capturing with Fiddler doesn't depend on wheather it's a first, second or third party application. You only need to ensure that the client sends http requests via the proxy provided by Fiddler. If you want to *programmatically* trace these requests you should have a look at the link provided by L.B. as comment to your question. Fiddler also supports FiddlerScript to modify requests/responses, filtering etc.